# Absolute value of function with finitely many discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Suppose that $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function with finitely many discontinuities. A question I'm solving relates to showing the absolute value of $f$ is Riemann integrable. I've finished most of the proof, but I'm stuck on demonstrating that $|f|$ has finitely many discontinuities. I'm sure there are proofs of this this fact online, but I'm just looking for a hint (or two...).

Here are a few thoughts I have so far. Suppose $f$ is not continuous at a finite number of points. If $c \in [a,b]$ is a point discontinuity where, for some $\epsilon > 0$, we have that $f(c - \epsilon)$, $f(c + \epsilon)$, and $f(c)$ are all positive, then taking the absolute value will have no effect. If, on the other hand, $f(c-\epsilon)$ and $f(c +\epsilon)$ are positive and $f(c)$ is negative, then either $|f|$ will still be discontinuous at $c$ or the absolute value "fills the gap," so to speak, and makes the function continuous at $c$. One example of this would be,

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \text{ if } x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}) \text{ and if } x\in (\frac{1}{2}, 1] \\
-0.25 \; \; \; \text{ if } x = 1/2 \\
\end{cases}$$

You can continue this kind of argumentation on a case by case basis, but this seems inefficient and over-complicated. Can someone suggest some hints of strategies that might simplify this?

Comment: Note that $||x| - |y|| \le |x - y|$, so $|f|$ is continuous wherever $f$ is.

Comment: @Izralbu Gotcha –– with my example, does that just show that there may be instances in which the absolute value of $f$ has fewer discontinuities? Could you, from this, then say that the number of discontinuities in $|f|$ is less than or equal to the number of discontinuities of $f$?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  (QWERTY)

Comment: "If the discontinuities are simply holes where the function is not defined" That can't happen since you assumed $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R.$

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for catching that! Fixed.